# How do I know when to perform IPLTEXT?

Tags: mainframe, zos

Ignoring HOLDDATA instructing me to do so, is there a specific module that would be modified by maintenance that should signal me that I need to write IPLTEXT to my IPL volume?

I typically just see if SYS1.NUCLEUS gets modified and write IPLTEXT regardless, but I wasn't sure if there was a 100% reliable way to know in case the HOLDDATA neglects to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [wait state 019](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=wsc-019) that I only saw once in my career when a sysprog accidentally pointed their ICKDSF IPLTEXT JCL to SYS1.SAMPLIB on the previous OS level instead of the new OS level.  So other than that mistake, I don't think the system will complain at IPL time about other possible updates, which I think is what you are addressing.

What about checking SYS1.SAMPLIB(IPLRECS) and SYS1.SAMPLIB(IEAIPL00) for updates, which (unless things have changed since I last wrote out IPLTEXT) are the source for the IPL records on the res pack?

Comment: Thanks, Tom! Looking at my IPLTEXT job these two members are still referenced and it hasn't failed me yet!

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully no one outside of IBM is updating the IPLText and when they do a HOLDDATA is the way they *should* communicate it.

Now if you have IPLTEXT for other than z/OS then you'll have to check with those (i.e. the stand alone editor ZZSA found on [www.cbttape.org](http://www.cbttape.org) in File 538).

Comment: I don't know how secureboot (secureipl) will play into this.

Comment: see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=zos-what-is-validated-boot

Comment: For Validated Boot, you really need to plan on re-signing everything every time you install service.  Strictly speaking, you don't have to, but it's easiest to just include signing into the process and then not worry about it going forward.